# Database upload not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to upload the name of an image and the name of the user to a database already created and its not working. Everything in the code is working(putting the file in the file system etc) less putting the name of the file in the database. I've tried without the ,now() and everything and its still not working.

```
 <?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

if($_FILES['image']['name'])
{
    $fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);
    $db_file_name = date("DMjGisY")."".rand(1000,9999).".".$fileExt;  
    $destination_path = getcwd()."/user/$log_username/$db_file_name";
    $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO photos(user,filename) VALUES('$log_username', '$db_file_name',now()))";

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    if($query)
    echo "Image uploaded";
    else
    echo "ERROR";
    /*<script> location.replace('../user.php?u=<?php echo $log_username;?>'); </script> */
?>
```

Comment: share the error. So that people can actually get an idea about your problem.

Comment: The ERROR is my echo, there is no actual error from the php

Comment: Try this.  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db_conx));

Comment: Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: Problem is with your sql query, please check my answer.

Comment: regarding your error, you have one bracket `)` too many. deleting it may very well fix your code. Do `now())";` instead of `now()))";`

Comment: so, where are we with this question; solved? still unclear?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm guessing he did find a solution to his problem.

Comment: @LoganWayne the question's been voted out as off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your sql query. It has a binding error & an extra parenthesis.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO photos(user,filename) VALUES('$log_username', '$db_file_name',now())";
```

You are specifying two fields `user,filename` but passing three args `'$log_username', '$db_file_name',now()`

Correct query would be (assuming you have an `DEFAULT` Time stamp column in the table, otherwise you have to specify the column name for that field as well),

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO photos(user,filename) VALUES('$log_username', '$db_file_name')";
```

Comment: Still got an extra `)` in your correct query.

Comment: You still have an extra `)` in your correct query. I'll edit this for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note:

- Your `$query` returns `false` because your query statement is wrong. You try to bind **three** `VALUES` on only **two** `columns`.
- You have extra `)` in your query inside `$sql` variable.

Your `$sql` query should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photos(user, filename)
                    VALUES('$log_username', '$db_file_name')";
```

Or if you have a `datetime` data type column in your photos table, it should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photos(user, filename, datecolumn) /* REPLACE NECESSARY COLUMN */
                    VALUES('$log_username', '$db_file_name', now())";
```